# Can a Sylow $p$-subgroup be conjugate to anything other than another Sylow $p$-subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, sylow-theory

The Sylow theorems say that all $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate.

Is that the only thing they are conjugate to? In other words could a $p$-Sylow subgroup also be conjugate to something that is not a $p$-Sylow group?

Or does the fact that every element with order dividing $p$ is in a $p$-Sylow group mean that that is never possible?

Comment: Conjugate subgroups are always isomorphic. Among other things this implies that they have the same cardinality.

Comment: Does that rule out the possibility that a $p$-Sylow subgroup could be isomorphic to a non $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Yes. If $Q$ is conjugate to a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$, then $|Q|=|P|$, meaning that $Q$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: As @JyrkiLahtonen is pointing out, the "Sylow" adjective is all about size, and conjugation preserves size.

Comment: Conjugation is a bijective map, so all $p$-Sylow subgroups are isomorphic and the isomorphism preserves cardinality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this question an answer, here is *Jyrki Lahtonen*'s answer:

> Conjugate subgroups are always isomorphic. Among other things this implies that they have the same cardinality.

So p-Sylow subgroups are always isomorphic to other p-Sylow subgroups.